# Are Custom Objects Passed by value or passed by Reference in Fragments and Activities.?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

hello Java and Android Experts. I am having a Problem.
I am making a XMPP based chat Application. There are a few things that are confusing me.

I have a class named Room_Structure which implements **Serializable**. This class has an object named **currentRoom**.

If i am passing **currentroom** object between two fragments by putting it in a bundle its working fine and surprisingly it is passed by reference. i dont know why is that. It shouldnt behave like this. btw i am using Android Support library?

But if i am passing that **currentRoom** object between Activities using a bundle and putting that bundle in an intent then i am getting a crash whenever i try to start a new activity using that intent.

For More Description Here is the Code

```
public class Room_Structure implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String Rname;
    private ArrayList<Message_Pattern> msg_list;
    private MultiUserChat XmppSession;
    private boolean Background;
    private boolean Modified;
    private boolean Destroyed;
}
```

The above class has constructors as well as getter and setters.

**Now Here is What i am doing:**

Consider That currentRoom object has already been populated and here is how i am Passing it to Fragment

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("RoomObject", currentRoom);
    Fragment_Chat newChat = new Fragment_Chat();
    newChat.setArguments(b);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fl_chatFragment, newChat);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

retrieving it from Fragment_Chat OnActivityCreated() method like this

```
Bundle extras = getArguments();
Room_Structure recievedRoom = (Room_Structure) extras.getSerializable("RoomObject");
```

Now this above code is working Just fine for **Fragments**. the only problem is that the object's reference is passed to the new fragment. Which is not how it should really behave. It should just send value not reference.

Here is how i know that objects are passed by reference

```
Sending Object : com.software.chat.Classes.Room_Structure@425585e8
Recieved Object: com.software.chat.Classes.Room_Structure@425585e8
```

both have same reference or Address. Checked it out during **Debugging**

**Now i cant replicate this behavior in Activities**

I have an Activity which contains a ExpandibleListView. I have implemented the adapter for this Expandiblelistview by extending it from BaseExpandableListAdapter. This adapter class name is Websites_ListAdapter.java. It is also passed activity's context in its constructor.
And i have made a layout clickable in the list. And i want to start an activity when that is clicked. please Don't ask why i did this its a long story.
I am Sending this object from that Websites_ListAdapter like this

```
Intent i=new Intent(ActivityContext, ChatScreen.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("RoomObject", currentRoom);
    i.putExtras(b);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    ActivityContext.startActivity(i);
```

But i get this error in Logcat This time when i call ActivityContext.startActivity(i)

```
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing 

serializable object (name = com.software.chat.Classes.Room_Structure)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6814)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity

(ActivityManagerNative.java:1910)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1415)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult

(FragmentActivity.java:817)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at com.software.chat.Adapters.Websites_ListAdapter$1.onClick

(Websites_ListAdapter.java:211)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: 

org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal

(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject

(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal

(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
04-25 15:38:07.474: E/AndroidRuntime(10250):    ... 24 more
```

**I know there are many ways to pass objects between activities  but i want to know why is it happening this way and what does serializable do in the background ?**

Any Help regarding this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you don't create the activity object as you do with fragments, you ask the system to do it. You create an intent in order to ask the system to create the activity, every thing in the intent is serialized and then passed through the system to the new activity. It is not possible to create two activities at the same time sharing the same object.
If you really need the same object reference you can always create a singleton.

Comment: In case of serialization, it should always create a copy of instance. but my test shows after serialization and De-serlization... both the objects refer to same instance in case of fragments. I dont understand how this can be possible.

Comment: @SaqibSaud you are referencing the same bungle object in the fragment and in the activity. They are the same. The bundle method putSerializable does not serialize the object until you serialize the bundle itself. When you pass the bundle in an intent from one activity to the other it gets serialized by the system.

Comment: @SherazKhilji it is normal java behavior. Activities are different because you always need to serialize the data to communicate between them.

Comment: @nicous Even though my problem was not solved like the way i wanted it. In the end i had to pass a key btw activities and then get my required object from a Singleton class using a hashmap .but now i have a better understanding of the Android Fragments and Activities thanks to your explanation. Thanku i really appreciate ur help :)

Answer (score 4):

If you'll look into [Bundle](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/os/Bundle.java#Bundle.putSerializable%28java.lang.String,java.io.Serializable%29) sources you'll see that it uses Map for storing objects and will only serialize objects when Bundle itself is serialized.

It seems that Bundle is not serialized when passed to fragments. It can be optimization trick or implementation "bug".

But when you want to start new activity Bundle will be serialized and than deserialized. Thats why you have this exception only for Activities.

Comment: Thanks @ MatrixDev So can you tell me how can i solve this problem. Is there any alternative approach to send data?

Comment: you can implement Serializable interface for all objects you want to pass. Non-serializable objects (like MultiUserChat in your case) can be stored in global Application object or static variables.

Comment: But cant we imitate the same behavior as in the case of Fragments?

Comment: As far as I know we can't dirrectly pass objects by reference when starting activity.

Comment: Why are reference being passed in case of Fragments. Its not normal behaviour is it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here :

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: 

org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat
```

The answer is:

```
public Class MultiUserChat implements Serializable
```